# Null data in result of running DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an API for an existing project. I created a serializer for for it and created a view as well, Although by opening browsable API , i get the empty brackets. 
here are the views :

```
class GroupAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    queryset = Group.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)


class GroupMemberAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GroupMemberSerializer
    queryset = GroupMember.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

serializers are :

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = "__all__"
    # fields = ['name']
class GroupMemberSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GroupMember
        fields = "__all__"
```

and here is what I see as a result:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
{},
{},
{},
{}
```

]

Why is it showing me null data although there is some data present in these models. Someone help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `serializers.ModelSerializer` instead of `serializers.Serializer`

Answer (score 2):

You should inherit `ModelSerializer` instead of `serializer`

```
class GroupMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GroupMember
        fields = "__all__"

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = "__all__"
```